# Oracle Database create automatic partition by range (long)

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I need a lot of partition table from one of my col table and dataType is long so I don't think can do it with hardcode in Sql syntax , now my question is what can i do for partition tables with range of long and automatic keyword in oracle database 19c?

Edit : I have Timestamp formated in long and I don't want to change it date type timestamp so I need every month split to separate partition I will convert all timestamp to long and store in database (because i need to reformat my timestamp to other format like gregorian or jalali and store it long make my job easier)

Comment: That's horrible. Don't use LONGS for timestamps. In fact don't use LONGS. LONGS were deprecated about a decade ago.

Comment: @BobC what can i use? number(10) or like that? and what can i do for range partition ?

Comment: Use DATE or TIMESTAMP